# I want to fit a linear regression model, but I know that if I treat each instance as unique there will be many pseudo replicates

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, meta-analysis, cluster-sample, pseudorepliction

I want to fit a linear regression model, but I know that if I treat each instance as unique there will be many pseudo replicates.

I want to explore the relationship between 2 binary variables and one continuous variable, I have data measured from 2 separate years (2021 and 2022). An example of this would be exploring the effect of Drug A, Drug B and interaction term Drug A*Drug B on Blood Pressure. I also want to include demographic information in my model (age and sex). Data is collected over 2 separate years for some patients, so about 50% of patients have data available from 2021 and 2022, while some patients only have data available from 2022 or 2021.

I want to fit a linear regression model, but I know that if I treat each instance as unique there will be many pseudo replicates. If there were many measures for each patient, then I believe that a mixed effects model could be appropriate, but since there are 1 or 2 measures for each variable, **I do not think a mixed effects model is appropriate**.

My question is, do you have any suggestions for how to analyze this data?

Note: The person that I am doing this for also wants p-values. I believe that this makes avoiding **pseudoreplication** more important.

Comment: I don't know why you think a mixed-effects model is not appropriate here. Just fit a mixed-effects model that adds subject as a random effect, which allows the two responses of subjects measured twice to be correlated.

Comment: A mixed effects model with random intercept can work for your data despite the low nr of level 1 units. However, you could also use single-level regression with [clustered standard errors](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/05/clustered-standard-errors-with-r/) or [robust standard errors](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjPlot/articles/tab_model_robust.html)